# Create relation code First Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a model:

```
   public class Delivery
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Guid BusinessId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PriceDisc> PriceDisc { get; set; }
    }

    public class PriceDisc
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public Guid BusinessId  { get; set; }

    }
```

How to create relation one to many between Delivery.BusinessId and PriceDisc.BuissnessId?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have already created a one to many relationship between them `Delivery` hold collection of `PriceDisc` in your code so for one `Delivery.BusinessId` you have collection of `PriceDisc.BusinessId`